# How to config submenus in Orchard CMS(v1.6) using contoso theme?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

Orchard CMS version is **1.6**, and **Contoso** is current theme.

Main Menu in Navigation zone.

Four menu items have been created: **News, submeun-1, submenu-2 and About**

Now I want to make menu structure as **submenu-1 and submenu-2 are submenus of News**.

In Orchard Navigation section I have drag submenu-1 and submenu-2 into News, see pic below:

[image]

But actually, the menus navigation looks like below:

[image]

**Expect: Mouse hover News Menu item, submenu-1 and submenu-2 popup.**

How to fix this bug? Thank you all!

Comment: Look at how the theme machine does it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for Bertrand Le Roy advise.

This work has been done by **changing contoso theme CSS file**.

Answer (score 0):

This will hide the nested menu until you hover on the parent menu li:

```
nav .menu li:hover > ul li {
  display: list-item;
}
nav .menu li ul li {
  display: none;
}
```